# 「漢字《よみがな》」にマッチするパターン

Tags: 正規表現, vim

Vim-KaoriYa 8.0.39 (64bit) を使用しています。

```
　吾輩《わがはい》は猫《ねこ》である。名前《なまえ》はまだ無い。
```

のように漢字の後に括弧書きで読み仮名が書かれているShift_JIS（cp932）の文章があり、それをVimで

```
　<吾輩|わがはい>は<猫|ねこ>である。<名前|なまえ>はまだ無い。
```

のように置換編集したいのですが、`漢字《よみがな》`にマッチするパターンがわからず困っています。

Vim-KaoriYaでは連続する漢字や平仮名、片仮名がそれぞれ１単語と見なされる（ように見受けられる）ので、`\<.\{-1,}\>《.\{-1,}》`で行けるかと思ったのですが、最短一致させているにも関わらず何故か

```
吾輩《わがはい》
は猫《ねこ》
である。名前《なまえ》
```

の３つにマッチしてしまいます。

何故このような結果になるのでしょうか。正しくマッチさせるにはどのようなパターンにすれば良いでしょうか。

なお、読み仮名が振られている漢字の直前に別の漢字がある場合（`焼肉定食《ていしょく》`のような）は考えなくて良いものとします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

raspbian jessie vim 7.4.488 にて、
`%s/\([一-龠]*\)《\([^》]*\)》/<\1\2>/g`
で置換できましたが、`焼肉定食《ていしょく》`も `<焼肉定食ていしょく>` になってしまうと思います。

Comment: なるほど、全漢字にマッチはそういうふうに書けたんですね。質問に書き忘れてて申し訳ないのですが、Shift-JIS（cp932）の場合はどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: ファイルのエンコーディングに関係無くVimのencodingがutf-8ならこれで良いようでした。

Answer (score 2):

漢字や平仮名にマッチさせるなら、Unicodeの`\p{Han}`や`\p{Hiragana}`を使いたくなります。vimではこのような指定はできません。・・・できるのかな？

素直に外部プログラムに投げてしまってはどうですか？

```
:%!perl -Mutf8 -ple 'BEGIN { binmode $_, ":encoding(cp932)" for *STDIN, *STDOUT; } s/(\p{Han}+)《(\p{Hiragana}+)》/<\1|\2>/g'
```

最短一致は`\{-}`ですが(`:help non-greedy`)、`.`は任意の一文字にマッチしますので(`:help /.`)、漢字だろうが平仮名だろうが前のマッチより後全てにマッチします。

Comment: vim は Unicode の `\p{class}` に対応していませんね…。ちなみに、`吾輩《わがはい》`という表記は青空文庫形式のルビに相当すると思いますので、`《》` の中にはカタカナが入る場合があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます、`:help non-greedy`に書いてある「早い位置でマッチするものが短いマッチよりも優先される」のところを逆だと誤解しておりました。自分のパターンが上手く行かない謎が解けました。 @metropolis はい、質問をややこしくしないために（おっしゃる通り色々パターンがあるので）伏せていましたが、確かに青空文庫の形式です。